# How to remove specific class from input with multiple classes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to check if the `input` has any character in it, then I sould add an `active` class to it and when it's empty then I should remove the `active` class. It's working only if the `input` only has the `active` class. Could you help me to improve my code to be able to remove ONLY the `active` class even if it has more?

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="lastname" onblur="checkInput(this)" />
    <label for="lastname" class="required">Lastname</label>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="invalid" class="invalid" onblur="checkInput(this)" />
    <label for="invalid">Firstname</label>
</div>

<script>
    var checkInput = function(input) {
        if (input.value.length > 0) {
            input.className = 'active';
        } else {
            input.className = '';
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: `input.classList.add(...)` and `input.classList.remove(...)` are better alternatives

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onChange` event handler instead of `onblur`
Check the [link](https://codepen.io/shakogele/pen/mzWPKw)
use

```
input.classList.add('active')
input.classList.remove('active')
```

Comment: Did you readed question?

Comment: Updated Code and answer now check please